# Detecting and removing undesired cells in Python pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is nested, as in the values of several columns' worth of cells are 1-row dataframes themselves.  Each dataframe-within-a-dataframe should have either 3 columns, or 5 columns, like so:

```
ColumnA             ColumnB
'abc','def','ghi'   123,456,789,012,345  
'zyx','wvu','tsr'   987,654,321,098,765
```

(The data is from an external source, so I have no control over it.) Once I receive the data, I expand it all into non-nested dataframes, and merge them:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6   Col7   Col8
abc    def    ghi    123    456    789    012    345
zyx    wvu    tsr    987    654    321    098    765
```

Recently, I was sent a 1-row dataframe-within-a-dataframe that was supposed to have 3 columns, but actually had 4.  In effect, my merged dataframe now has one extra cell; this throws off the entire merged dataframe, since everything below and to the right of that extra cell is now populated with values that should be in a different column. For example:

```
Col1   Col2   XColX   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6   Col7   Col8
abc    def    XXXXX   ghi    123    456    768    012    345
zyx    wvu    tsr     987    654    321    098    765    NaN
```

I don't want to just get rid of this one extra cell this one time; I want to make sure this doesn't happen again! In other words, I don't want to detect and remove the wrong pattern that did happen; I want to dictate and enforce the right pattern that should happen.

Using pandas/python/regex/numpy/whatever, how do I make sure that these 1-row dataframes-within-dataframes are only allowed to contain columns from a preapproved list of column names?

ETA: On request, here's the code used to expand the data into non-nested frames:

```
ColumnA_vals = df['ColumnA'].str.extractall(r'([\w\d]+)=([^,\)]*)') 
ColumnA_converted = ColumnA_vals.unstack(level=-1)[1] 
ColumnA_converted.columns = list(ColumnA_vals.unstack(level=-1)[0].values[0])
colnames = ColumnA_converted.columns
ColumnA_converted.columns = [x for x in colnames]
df2 = df.drop(['ColumnA'], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([ColumnA_converted, df2], axis=1)
# lather-rinse-repeat for each of the original un-prettied columns provided
```

This will make more sense if you know that the actual 1-row dataframes-within-dataframes look like this:

```
IdA(Col1='abc',Col2='def',Col3='ghi')
```

Comment: You can check the length of the elements in each column. What do you want to happen if for example your first column cells has 4 elements instead of expected 3?

Comment: I want to drop the element that has the wrong column name

Comment: `list(ColumnA_vals.unstack(level=-1)[0].values[0])` does extract all of the correct `itemX` values. For `itemE='strc'`, `'strc'` is incorrectly placed in column `itemB`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney My mistake when typing up the example, but it does work fine on the real data (which needs to stay anonymous).

Comment: Worth mentioning that I found a solution for this particular problem that avoided the problem entirely, but I still want to know how to solve this particular problem.